# И что же? (--) Всё осталось, как было. Можно ли поставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

Пришли мы вчера на работу. И что же? -- Всё осталось, как было.

- Есть ли такое правило, которое допускает постановку тире в таких случаях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставить тире можно, но не в начале предложения (это будет открытием или продолжением прямой речи).

А вот вопросительный знак в середине предложения никто не отменял, и фраза может быть такой: «*И что же? — всё осталось, как было*».

Answer (score 2):

**Пришли мы вчера на работу. И что же? Всё осталось, как было.**

А зачем тире? Пауза между предложениями не короче паузы, обозначенной тире.

Comment: Вопрос: есть ли правило?

Comment: Нет правила. Тире между предложениями ставится при оформлении прямой речи.  Здесь же, как я понимаю, хочется сделать паузу и поставить интонационное тире. Но пауза и так есть, без тире.